# R Markdown: Must the author's name be italic?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have found that when I use R Markdown, the author's name is in italic.

Just like this:

[image: SS of Rmarkdown output]

Can I set it in roman?

The reason I ask these question because I am Chinese. If I write my name in Chinese and in italic type, it can be a little bit ugly...

So what can I do now?

Comment: @Hack-R, if you uncomment your yaml and reprocess, you will find the author is *italicised* in the default pandoc template.

Comment: @Hack-R, I'm not sure what you mean, your image is not the result of a valid yaml header

Comment: Thank you all~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add CSS to change if your output is `html` or edit the `pandoc` template for `LaTeX`.

#### Default Template

[image]

#### With CSS in your `YAML` for `html` output

```
    author: <h4 style="font-style:normal">Author Name</h4>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I want!

Comment: @Chang Xiao, no worries. If this answer meets your expected solution, please mark it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's easier if you use `\emph{}` in author as:

```
author: \emph{Some Name}
```

This will reverse the italic and make it roman provided the fact you are building a pdf with Latex.

Hope this helped!